# What do you call the non-terminal nodes of a syntax tree?

Tags: terminology, syntax-trees

Suppose I have the following syntax tree:

[image]

Is there a term for the nodes identified by "S", "NP", "VP", and "V"? For a generic tree, I guess you would just call them "non-terminal nodes" or "branch nodes", but I was wondering if there was a term for those nodes that is specifically used in the context of syntax.

Comment: _Non-terminal (node)_ is the correct term. If you're being extremely formal, _labelled non-terminal node_.

Comment: No, I wouldn't, thank you. Feel free to accept it anyway, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jlawler writes](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/4613/what-do-you-call-the-non-terminal-nodes-of-a-syntax-tree#comment12500_4613) that *non-terminal (node)* is, in fact, the correct term here. He also notes that, if you want to be extremely formal, you can call it a *labeled non-terminal node*.

Answer (score 0):

A Category, is a more generic term, but when it comes natural language process or Finite state automata, *non-terminal* node is the correct term